# Reloading only new data after dismissing previous VC

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parsing, uirefreshcontrol

So I have a  Photo VC where I can post an image and a caption as outlined below:

```
@IBAction func postPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    if imageOutlet.imageView?.image != UIImage(named: "plus_photo") && postImageTextField.text.count >= 5 && postImageTextField.text != "Write a caption..." {
        var userProfileImageData = Data()
        let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
        query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.current()?.username)
        query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects: [PFObject]?,error: Error?) in
        if let objects = objects {
            for object in objects {
                let userImageFile = object["profilePic"] as? PFFileObject
                userImageFile?.getDataInBackground(block: { (userProfileImageData1: Data?, error: Error?) in
                    if error == nil {
                        userProfileImageData = userProfileImageData1!
                    let currentDateTime = Date()
                                   let formatter = DateFormatter()
                                   formatter.timeStyle = .short
                                   formatter.dateStyle = .none
                                   let captionData = self.postImageTextField.text
                                   let userPhoto = PFObject(className: "PicPost")
                                let imageData = self.imageOutlet.imageView?.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1)!
                                   let imageFile = PFFileObject(name: "image.png", data: imageData!)
                                    let imageFile2 = PFFileObject(name: "image.png", data: userProfileImageData)


                        userPhoto["ProfilePhoto"] = imageFile2
                        userPhoto["Bar"] = self.barText
                        userPhoto["ImageFile"] = imageFile
                        userPhoto["UserCaption"] = captionData
                        userPhoto["UserLikes"] = 0
                        userPhoto["UserTime"] = (formatter.string(from: currentDateTime))
                        userPhoto["Username"] = PFUser.current()?.username
                        userPhoto.saveInBackground { (success, error) in
                            if success {
                            self.postImageTextField.resignFirstResponder()
                            //Go back to original VC
                            self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                            } else {
                                print(error)
                                self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

                            }
                        }


                    } else {
                        print(error)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    })
}
```

}

I dismiss this VC using the line:

```
            self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This new tableView VC has already loaded data:

```
    func getPicData() {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "PicPost")
    query.whereKey("Bar", equalTo: BarText!)
    query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
    query.limit = picLimit
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects: [PFObject]?,error: Error?) in
        if let objects = objects {
            for object in objects {
                self.picsLoaded = true
                let ImageFile = object["ImageFile"] as? PFFileObject
                let urlString = ImageFile?.url as! String
                if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
                    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
                    if let imageData = data {
                        self.picPostPicUrlArray.append(urlString as NSString)
                        self.picPostPicImageCache.setObject(UIImage(data:imageData)!,forKey: urlString as NSString)
                    }
                }
                let ProfileImageFile = object["ProfilePhoto"] as? PFFileObject
                let urlString2 = ProfileImageFile?.url as! String
                if let url2 = URL(string: urlString2) {
                    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url2)
                    if let imageData = data {
                        self.picPostProPicUrlArray.append(urlString2 as NSString)
                        self.picPostProPicImageCache.setObject(UIImage(data: imageData)!, forKey: urlString2 as NSString)
                    }
                }
                if object["UserLikes"] != nil && object["Username"] != nil && object["UserTime"] != nil {
                self.picLikeArray.append(object["UserLikes"] as! Int)
                self.picUsernameArray.append(object["Username"] as! String)
                self.picTimeArray.append(object["UserTime"] as! String)
                self.picObjectIdArray.append(object.objectId!)
                self.picCaptionArray.append(object["UserCaption"] as! String)

                }
            }
            self.Reload()
        }
    })
}
```

As you can see, the function getPicData() has already loaded all of the data from parse.com. It is stored in various arrays.

What I would like to do, is to load only the new data and add it to the current tableView. What I tried doing was to segue from the PhotoVC to the tableView VC. The new segue would then reload all of the data(). Unfortunately, this is very bad for my memory.

The two problems I need to solve:

1) load only new data and load it to current table view
2) dismiss the tableView VC to go back to homescreen. Right now it dismisses to the one it just came from, which is the post VC.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For your first problem for adding new data to your existing arrays available. You can use delegate method in PhotoVC to pass new posted object to your previous controller i.e. in your case tableView VC . Here is code snippet for delegation between two classes .

```
protocol PhotoVCdelegate : class{
   func postAdded(item : PFObject)    
}

class PhotoVC{
   weak var delegate : PhotoVCdelegate?

   @IBAction func postPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
if imageOutlet.imageView?.image != UIImage(named: "plus_photo") && postImageTextField.text.count >= 5 && postImageTextField.text != "Write a caption..." {
    var userProfileImageData = Data()
    let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.current()?.username)
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects: [PFObject]?,error: Error?) in
    if let objects = objects {
        for object in objects {
            let userImageFile = object["profilePic"] as? PFFileObject
            userImageFile?.getDataInBackground(block: { (userProfileImageData1: Data?, error: Error?) in
                if error == nil {
                    userProfileImageData = userProfileImageData1!
                let currentDateTime = Date()
                               let formatter = DateFormatter()
                               formatter.timeStyle = .short
                               formatter.dateStyle = .none
                               let captionData = self.postImageTextField.text
                               let userPhoto = PFObject(className: "PicPost")
                            let imageData = self.imageOutlet.imageView?.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1)!
                               let imageFile = PFFileObject(name: "image.png", data: imageData!)
                                let imageFile2 = PFFileObject(name: "image.png", data: userProfileImageData)


                    userPhoto["ProfilePhoto"] = imageFile2
                    userPhoto["Bar"] = self.barText
                    userPhoto["ImageFile"] = imageFile
                    userPhoto["UserCaption"] = captionData
                    userPhoto["UserLikes"] = 0
                    userPhoto["UserTime"] = (formatter.string(from: currentDateTime))
                    userPhoto["Username"] = PFUser.current()?.username
                    userPhoto.saveInBackground { (success, error) in
                        if success {
                        self.postImageTextField.resignFirstResponder()
                        //Go back to original VC

                       //HERE you can pass this information to your controller
                        self.delegate?.postAdded(item : userPhoto)


                        self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                        } else {
                            print(error)
                            self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

                        }
                    }


                } else {
                    print(error)
                }
            })
        }
    }
})
   }
}
```

In your TableViewVC.swift
let assume you have function to present controller on button click.

```
class TableViewVC{ 

    @IBAction func createPostBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
       if let vc =    self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"PhotoVC") as? PhotoVC{
           vc.delegate = self
           self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
         }
     }

}
```

delegate method of PhotoVC will be called when you post data successfully.

```
extension TableViewVC : PhotoVCdelegate{ 
    func postAdded(item : PFObject){ 
          // append required value from item object into your arrays and reload tableview . 

     }
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: I have a problem though. When I set the new image to the image cache, it adds it to the end. So now the imageCache shows the newest image at the last of the tableview as opposed to the first.

Comment: Why are you saving image on your local database . Save image url on your end . fetch this images on every cellfor_rowatindexpath delegate method of table view . Use Kingfisher library (https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)  . It automatically saved image for a given url .